# jQuery selector not matching elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some jQuery that is causing me a little head ache at the moment. It all boils down to how the selector is working.

I have some HTML in the form of:

```
<div id="master">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-6 columns">
            <div class="medium-6 right columns">
                <div class="pagerContent">
                    <div class="pagination">
                        <div class="page">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">
                          ......
etc.
```

Which contains a bunch anchor tags which from part of my navigation.

If I use the following jQuery.

```
$('#master').on('click', '.pagination a', function (event) {

    -- code --

});
```

It works, but if I use

```
$(".pagination a", "#master").on('click', function (event) {

    -- code --

});
```

It does not.

Comment: $(".pagination a, #master")

Comment: remove comma. this should works this `$(".pagination a, #master")` . please have small look https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: @AlexandrMalyita that has a much different intent than the OP's code. Using a second parameter to the jQuery selector `$()` should target a parent element. You've essentially changed that to an AND.

Comment: Are your _anchor tags_ getting created on the fly?  Maybe that is the reason cz if all the html is present when _DOM_ is ready that second code should work.

Comment: @ManpreetSingh - That selector will select both _master_ div as well as anchors inside _pagination_ div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and thanks for everyone replies not this. I was still having difficulties getting this to work, so I have tried a different way which does work for me.

For each of the link tags, I have defined a specific class as an identifier so

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

became

```
<a href="#" class="myFirstLink"></a>
```

then using

```
$(document).on("click", "myFirstLink", function (event) {
        alert("Hi," + event.target.href + " clicked");
    });
```

I am now able to process the links.

Answer (score 3):

Your two examples are subtly different.

This, uses deferred event handling.

```
$('#master').on('click', '.pagination a', function (event) {

    -- code --

});
```

Essentially the `click` is handled by `#master` and only fires when the selector `.pagination a` is matched by the clicked element. This way works if any children/descendants are dynamically added to the page after DOM load.

This, does not:

```
$(".pagination a", "#master").on('click', function (event) {

    -- code --

});
```

It attaches the `click` event directly to "descendants of `#master` matching `.pagination a`" and as such requires that the elements are present in the DOM when the handler is attached.